# Java: For loop not displaying counter

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, printf, counter

I am trying to use a for loop to display an element of an arraylist and also its counter. The output is currently only showing the first counter in loop (i.e 0) But doesnt show the rest. e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 6...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d %.2f",i, al.get(i));
}
```

Example Output:

```
0 0.951 0.492 0.343 0.184 0.605 0.726 0.877 0.698 0.099 0.9310 0.22
```

Note how `0` is shown initially but not other counter...

Answer (score 8):

You need to add space in your format to separate previous value with current counter
(you need spaces in places marked `|`)

```
0 0.95|1 0.49|2 0.34|3 0.18|4 0.60|5 0.72|6 0.87|7 0.69|8 0.09|9 0.93|10 0.22
```

Use

```
System.out.printf("%d %.2f ",i, al.get(i));
```

You can also print each counter-value pair in new line. So instead of space use line separator. If you want OS dependent separator use `%n`.

```
System.out.printf("%d %.2f%n",i, al.get(i));
```

Comment: +1 I stared at that for several minutes trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it is displaying the counter, but because there is no new line or any separator characters printed, it looks like it's part of the previous value.  If the values are {0.95, 0.49, 0.34, ...} then you'll get this output.

```
     i: 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
 value:   0.95  0.49  0.34  0.18  0.60  0.72  0.87  0.69  0.09  0.93   0.22
Output: 0 0.951 0.492 0.343 0.184 0.605 0.726 0.877 0.698 0.099 0.9310 0.22
```

Place a space or a newline in your `print` format to visually separate your numbers.